# Is it possible to open a binary file with os.open and os.fdopen on Unix?

Tags: python, file, utf-8, python-os

I'm trying to stream a file to clients with Python, and I need to add the HTTP header fields in the response, namely `Content-Length` and `Last-Modified`. I found that I can access these fields from the file using [`os.fstat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fstat), which returns a [`stat_result`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result) object, giving me [`st_size`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result.st_size) and [`st_mtime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result.st_mtime) that I can use in the response header.

Now this `os.fstat` takes a *file descriptor*, which is provided by [`os.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open). This works:

```py
import os

file_name = "file.cab"

fd = os.open(file_name, os.O_RDONLY)
stats = os.fstat(fd)

print("Content-Length", stats.st_size) # Content-Length 27544
print("Last-Modified", stats.st_mtime) # Last-Modified 1650348549.6016183
```

Now to actually open this file and have a file object (so I can read and stream it), I can use [`os.fdopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fdopen), which takes the file descriptor provided by `os.open`.

```py
f = os.fdopen(fd)
print(f) # <_io.TextIOWrapper name=3 mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

We can see that the return object has `encoding` set to `UTF-8`. However, when I try to read the file, it gives an error:

```py
print(f.read())
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "{redacted}/stream.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(f.read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 60: invalid start byte
```

Now there's this *flag* called [`os.O_BINARY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.O_BINARY), but it's mentioned in the document that

> The above constants are only available on Windows.

And sure enough, since I'm running on a Unix machine, if I execute `os.open` with this flag, it gives an `AttributeError`:

```py
fd = os.open(file_name, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_BINARY)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{redacted}/stream.py", line 5, in <module>
    fd = os.open(file_name, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_BINARY)
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'O_BINARY'
```

So is it possible to open a binary file with `os.open` and `os.fdopen` on Unix?

Note that this problem doesn't occur if I just use the [built-in `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function:

```py
file_name = "file.cab"

f = open(file_name, 'rb')
print(f) # <_io.BufferedReader name='file.cab'>
print(f.read()) # throws up the file in my terminal
```

But I have to open it with the `os` module, because I need to provide those HTTP header fields I mentioned.

Edit: As mentioned by [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71920580/is-it-possible-to-open-a-binary-file-with-os-open-and-os-fdopen-on-unix#comment127087335_71920580), this is an example of an XY problem. I can get the result I want by using [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat), which doesn't necessarily take a file descriptor and can be used with just the file path. So I can do something like this:

```py
import os

file_name = "file.cab"

f = open(file_name, 'rb')
stats = os.stat(file_name)

print(f) # <_io.BufferedReader name='file.cab'>
print(stats) # os.stat_result(...)
```

So at this point, I'm only wondering how, or if, it's possible to do the same with `os.open` and `os.fdopen`.

Comment: This is interesting as such, but your actual question seems to be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). There are other and generally better ways to get the modification time and size of a file.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I figured that could be the case, so I also provided the reason that I'm doing this. But I find it odd if it's not possible.

Comment: The `os` documentation contains this snippet: *"`open()`, `io.open()`, and `codecs.open()` use the UTF-8 encoding by default. However, they still use the strict error handler by default so that attempting to open a binary file in text mode is likely to raise an exception rather than producing nonsense data."*

Comment: @tripleee Note that the snippet quoted is only true if UTF-8 Mode is activated.  See [PEP-540](https://peps.python.org/pep-0540/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Just tell os.fdopen() to open in binary mode:

```
f = os.fdopen(fd, 'rb')
```

Notice the hint in the [os.fdopen documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fdopen) ...

> This is an alias of the open() built-in function and accepts the same arguments.

... for [the args parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> 'r' open for reading (default)
>
> 'b' binary mode

Here's a full program to illustrate the difference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

filepath = "utf8.txt"

fd = os.open(filepath, os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY )
fo1 = os.fdopen(fd)
fo2 = os.fdopen(fd, 'rb')
print(fo1)
print(fo2)
```

Result:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name=3 mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.BufferedWriter name=3>
```

PS: I ran into this problem when trying to save an image using PIL.  The Image.save() method also accepts a file object / file descriptor. This one too has to be opened in binary mode.